# PHP Change CSS Style

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide a login button if the user is logged in. Due to the clients **Wordpress** setup, I'm not able to directly edit the button HTML.

**Button HTML (unable to edit):**

```
<li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-153">
  <a href="#">
     <span id="SignUp" class="et_pb_more_button et_pb_button">
       <p>SIGN UP</p>
     </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

My thoughts was to write a simple PHP if statement to change the CSS within the header.

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-item-153 {
                display: none;
      }
  </style>
<?php } ?>
```

However, the PHP echo outputs on the page but it doesn't change the CSS.

On inspection, it looks like the following:

[image]

Any suggestions here? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Just tried using a jQuery way with no luck:

```
<script>
    $( 'menu-item-153' ).css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

Comment: That's a CSS specificity issue. You can use `#menu-item-153 { display: none!important; }` or `#top-menu li#menu-item-153 { display: none; }`

Comment: you should put the condition on the html not the css

Comment: @MichaelCoker ahhh.. I need some sleep Thanks!!

Comment: @BaraaAl-Tabbaa So the HTML is loaded from MySQL so thats a nogo... yeah... weird developers created the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS specificity issue.  You can use

```
#top-menu li#menu-item-153 {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
#menu-item-153 {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Or if you want to do it with jQuery, you left off the `#` ID part of the selector

```
$('#menu-item-153').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: @hinteractive02 fo sho!

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP-part is functioning just as it should.

Your problem is that your "display:none;" is being overriden by another piece of styling:

```
#top-menu li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Make YOUR CSS selector more specifik to override this:
Use this:

```
#top-menu #menu-item-153 {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule with specificity of 101 points.

```
#top-menu /* id selector = 100 specificity points */

li        /* element selector = 1 specificity point */
```

The above rule is overriding another rule with a specificity of 100:

```
#menu-item-153 /* 100 specificity points */
```

You could use `!important` to quash the first rule and get it over with.

However, often times it's good to reserve `!important` for when it's *absolutely necessary*.

In this case, you just need 2 points for the preferred rule to prevail. This should do it:

```
li#menu-item-153.menu-item /* class selector = 10 specificity points (111 total) */
```

or

```
#top-menu > #menu-item-153 /* 200 specificity points */
```

More info: http://cssspecificity.com/